# Why below program is printing Object of different Array?

Tags: java, functional-programming

I am not able to  understand the internal working that is  happening behind the screen but I am confused because it is printing different result in console than what it is expected to. Could anybody resolve my problem with good explanation?

```
public class Demo {

public int [] sort(int h[])
{
    int temp;
    for(int i=0;i<h.length;i++)
    {
        for (int j=i;j<h.length;j++)
        {
            if(h[i]>h[j])
            {
                temp=h[i];
                h[i]=h[j];
                h[j]=temp;
            }

        }
    }
    return h;
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Demo obj =new Demo();
    int a[]={9,2,3,5,32,1,5,3,7};

    int[] sorted=obj.sort(a);

    /*Code to Display Array a*/
    for(int s :a)
    {   
     System.out.print(s+ "  ");
    }

     System.out.println("");


    /*Code to Display Array sorted*/
    for(int k:sorted)
    {   
     System.out.print(k+"  ");
    }
}

  /*
   Expected output
               9  2  3  5  32  1  5  3  7
               1  2  3  3  5   5  7  9  32  

   Actual output 
               1  2  3  3  5  5  7  9  32  
               1  2  3  3  5  5  7  9  32  
 */ 


}
```

Comment: Could you provide some more code and the output you get and the expected output...

Comment: I got my answer..Thank you for your concern

Comment: You could have marked any below answer as correct then. @Dhananjaya

Comment: I am new here. How can I do it?

Comment: No problem.. refer this.. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: and this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Great.. you did it.. all the best ahead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sort` method is working on the actual input parameter that is passed to the method by call-by-reference (I know this is not 100% correct in terms of wording - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)). That is, all changes to the array `h` in `sort`are visible in the calling code as well.

If you don't want to change the input parameter, you need to make a copy of the object. In your case you could use `System.arrayCopy` to do so.

Comment: Same  method I changed ,with an int but this time why it has not passed by reference.
public class prac {


 public int  square(int a)
 {
  
  
  return a*a;
    }
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  prac obj =new prac();
  int a=14;
    int k=obj.square(a);
 
   System.out.print(a+ "  ");
 
     System.out.println("");
 
   System.out.print(k+"  ");
  
    }
}
Out put is 
14 196

Comment: Yes, if you would have read the other question on call-by-reference in Java, you'd know that primitives are not passed by reference but by value. Furthermore you are not altering the input parameter `a` in your example but only using it's value for the computation...

Comment: I tried with Integer  it did pass by value. .Integer is not primitive

Comment: As said, you are not altering the value of `a` your example. Why should there be any changes? Furthermore `Integer` is one of many immutable classes. That is once you created an `Integer` it's not possible the make changes to this object anymore. Other immutable classes are `String`, `Byte`, `Short`, ...

Comment: You're welcome. Would you mind voting up answers that were helpful to you and perhaps marking the "best" answer as correct, to mark this question as answered...

Answer (score 0):

That is because when you are passing the array object,the array int []h  refers to the same memory location.

Consider int[]a as an object which has bytes representing the address of the array memory.Now when you pass this array, the same bytes get copied into int[]h so now , h also points to the same memory and therefore that memory gets modified.

Comment: Same  method I changed ,with an int but this time why it has not passed by reference.
public class prac {


 public int  square(int a)
 {
  
  
  return a*a;
    }
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  prac obj =new prac();
  int a=14;
    int k=obj.square(a);
 
   System.out.print(a+ "  ");
 
     System.out.println("");
 
   System.out.print(k+"  ");
  
    }
}

Comment: See now int a is not an object, it is a primitive, it stores the bit pattern of 14.The same bit pattern gets passed onto the method and it returns the bit pattern of 196 which gets saved in k.
A simple way to remember this is , objects get passed by reference and primitives get passed by value

Comment: I tried with Integer it is passing by value .Integer is an Object .how it worked?

Comment: Now bro,that is because Integer class is immutable.
when you perform an operation on Integer class,it gets unboxed to int, operations are performed and then again it is boxed to Integer.
This boxing , unboxing feature came with Java 5.
You'll get similar results with String,Double and other immutable wrapper classes